# Why controllerDidChangeContent is not being called?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Here is a simple scenario: assuming I have two Core Data entities: `A` and `B` with one to many relationship. (`A` can point to many `B`). 
When creating `NSFetchedResultsController` fetching all `A` objects, changing a property of any `A` object will trigger `controllerDidChangeContent` delegate method. However, changing a property of `B` object will not trigger this method. (although the changed `B` object is referenced by one of the `A` objects)

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post your code on where you're creating the `NSFetchedResultsController`? Chances are you need a different predicate.

Comment: I intentionally simplified the scenario above, as my code is much more complicated...  Can you suggest how the predicate is related to this issue?

Comment: @Jim's comment gets close to the issue. If you are looking for `A` but you change a property on `B`, your controller didn't change any content, because it's looking at `A`, not `B`.

Comment: I posted a new question related to this issue but with detailed code and clear explanation. I would be grateful if you take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446758/why-nsfetchedresultscontroller-is-not-being-updated-with-new-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This took some time to get my head around it. The fetched results controller evaluates the changes of its managed object context. Those changes only fire the fetched results controller delegate methods if they would meet the criteria set for its fetch. This includes matching the predicate conditions.

If your controller is fetching entities of type A, then it will only react to changes of entities of type B if those changes to B affect what is in A (and matching the predicate conditions abd maybe the sort descriptors, as well).

Can  you show the predicate in your question above? Can you show the relationships between A and B?

Comment: Not sure I get it... How theoretically can changes to B affect what is in A? These are two different objects well encapsulated (say A is author and B is book)

Comment: You are answering your own question. If changes to B do not affect A, why would you expect the fetched results controller to recognize the change. Unless there is a relationship change. Show the predicates and you will probably reveal what is really going on.

Comment: I posted a new question related to this issue showing all related code. It would be great if you can take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446758/why-nsfetchedresultscontroller-is-not-being-updated-with-new-data